# Qt QPushButton changes size when checked is enabled

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have two `QPushButton` on a `QGridLayout`, with one button checked and the other unchecked:

```
class MyFrame : QFrame()
{
    MyFrame() { init(); }

    void init()
    {
        setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color:#292929; color: white;} QPushButton:hover {background-color: #505050; color: white;} QPushButton:pressed{background-color: #F79862;} QPushButton:checked{background-color: #F79862;border:none;} QToolTip{ color: #404040; }");

        auto layout = new QGridLayout();
        auto btn1 = new QPushButton("btn1");
        auto btn2 = new QPushButton("btn2");

        btn1->setCheckable(true);
        btn2->setCheckable(true);

        btn1->setChecked(false);
        btn2->setChecked(true);

        layout->addWidget(btn1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        layout->addWidget(btn2, 0, 1, 1, 1);
    }
}

QVBoxLayout* grid = new QVBoxLayout();
MyFrame* myFrame = new MyFrame();
grid->addWidget(myFrame);
```

However, when i run the program, one of the button appears to be bigger than the other. What can I do to make the button size similar?

[image]

I am using Qt 5.11.2.

Comment: Does the size changes also when you change its state manually?

Comment: @SilvanoCerza no it doesn't

Comment: Could you add a picture and some more code showing how `layout` is used? Also which version of Qt you're building with?

Comment: @SilvanoCerza I have updated with more elaboration.

Comment: Seems like you're using a custom styleSheet here, the problem is probably there, could you share it?

Comment: You forgot to set the layout of `MyFrame`. It seems your style sheet is the cause of the problem. It works well without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your styleSheet, just remove `border:none;` from `QPushButton:checked`.

```
setStyleSheet("QPushButton {"
              "   background-color:#292929; "
              "   color: white;"
              "} "
              ""
              "QPushButton:hover {"
              "   background-color: #505050; "
              "   color: white;"
              "} "
              ""
              "QPushButton:pressed {"
              "   background-color: #F79862;"
              "} "
              ""
              "QPushButton:checked {"
              "   background-color: #F79862;"
              "} "
              ""
              "QToolTip { "
              "   color: #404040; "
              "}");
```

This is the result:

[image: Solution image]